# Is there an R function to find the instance number an element has appeared in a list based on certain conditions?

Tags: r, purrr, dplyr

I am trying to get the proper instance count of an alteration on a product and struggling. I feel like this should be easy but for the life of my I can't figure it out today and it's driving me nuts.

So below I have some sample code against dummy data:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(openxlsx)
library(olapR)
library(janitor)

file_path <- "C:\\Users\\user_name\\Desktop\\R_Question.xlsx"

df_file <- read.xlsx(file_path)

df_file <- df_file %>%
  clean_names() %>%
  mutate(actual_result = if_else((lag(product_type) == product_type &
                                  lag(claim_type) == claim_type &
                                  lag(date) != date),
                                  item_count + 1,
                                  item_count)
  ) %>% 
  replace(is.na(.), 1) %>% 
  mutate(actual_result = str_c("A", actual_result))

df_file
```

which produces:

```
date        order     product      claim_type  item_count desired_result  actual_result
2019-12-01  QN123456  Jacket       Alteration       1         A1              A1
2019-12-07  QN123456  Jacket       Alteration       1         A2              A2
2019-12-11  QN123456  Pants        Alteration       1         A1              A1
2019-12-13  QN123456  Pants        Alteration       1         A2              A2
2019-12-18  QN123456  Pants        Alteration       1         A3              A2
2019-12-19  QN123456  Pants        Alteration       1         A4              A2
```

Everything except the last column was part of the file read that was read in. The last column is added using the mutate. I am trying to get the actual results from the mutate to = the desired result column, but I keep ending up at the "actual result" column.

I've tried using purr::map() + function as well as a for loop, but I end up at the same result as the "actual_result" column.

I've also tried using cumsum(item_count) in place of item_count + 1 but it's not quite what I'm looking for, it produces:

```
date        order     product      claim_type  item_count desired_result  actual_result
2019-12-01  QN123456  Jacket       Alteration       1         A1              A1
2019-12-07  QN123456  Jacket       Alteration       1         A2              A2
2019-12-11  QN123456  Pants        Alteration       1         A1              A1
2019-12-13  QN123456  Pants        Alteration       1         A2              A4
2019-12-18  QN123456  Pants        Alteration       1         A3              A5
2019-12-19  QN123456  Pants        Alteration       1         A4              A6
```

... which is pretty close but not what I need

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, what you need is assign a unique number to each `product` and `claim_type`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
    group_by(product, claim_type) %>% 
    mutate(actual_result = paste0('A', row_number()))


#  date       order    product claim_type item_count desired_result actual_result
#  <fct>      <fct>    <fct>   <fct>           <int> <fct>          <chr>        
#1 2019-12-01 QN123456 Jacket  Alteration          1 A1             A1           
#2 2019-12-07 QN123456 Jacket  Alteration          1 A2             A2           
#3 2019-12-11 QN123456 Pants   Alteration          1 A1             A1           
#4 2019-12-13 QN123456 Pants   Alteration          1 A2             A2           
#5 2019-12-18 QN123456 Pants   Alteration          1 A3             A3           
#6 2019-12-19 QN123456 Pants   Alteration          1 A4             A4
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(date = structure(1:6, .Label = c("2019-12-01", 
"2019-12-07", "2019-12-11", "2019-12-13", "2019-12-18", "2019-12-19"
), class = "factor"), order = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = "QN123456", class = "factor"), product = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Jacket", "Pants"), class = "factor"), 
claim_type = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Alteration", 
class = "factor"),item_count = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
desired_result = structure(c(1L,2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), 
.Label = c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4"),class = "factor")),
row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak that did the trick. Don't know why I never thought of using group_by before. row_number is a new one for me!

Can you also explain why my original attempt using mutate did not work?

Comment: I think that is because when you are doing `item_count + 1` in `ifelse` it does not update the value of the previous iteration in `item_count`. `item_count` always remains 1. Probably, you need to use `cumsum` somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `str_c` which will also return `NA` if there are any NA values

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
   group_by(product, claim_type) %>% 
   mutate(actual_result = str_c('A', row_number()))
```

---

Or with `rowid` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, actual_result := paste0("A", rowid(product, claim_type))][]
```